# No repeat for text-labels on line?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am using

```
"symbol-placement": "line",
```

to add text labels over polygons (countries) using a precalculated line which spans the country bounds. However, the text label automatically repeats itself which does not look good.

Example: Instead of a curved GERMANY, I get a curved unwanted repetition GERMANY GERMANY GERMANY GERMANY.

I could not find any option for that... Is there a work around?

Bonus question:
Is it possible to have the text span the full line and have the font-size dynamically set accordingly? That would be the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `symbol-spacing` to a very high number (eg, 5000) should effectively achieve what you want.

> Bonus question: Is it possible to have the text span the full line and have the font-size dynamically set accordingly?

No. But you could set the length of the line as a property on the feature, and use data-driven styling to set the font size from that. Data-driven styling for font-sizes is supported in Mapbox-GL-JS as of version 0.35.

You could potentially also use `text-letter-spacing`. That one doesnt' supoprt data-driven styling, but you could use filters to set some basic classes of letter spacing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wm18a33d/136/

*symbol-spacing* is unfortunately not a solution, because it seems to prevent other nearby symbols (see top line) from showing up and justify/align center is then no longer working...

Comment: Hmm, that looks like a bug to me. Even with `text-allow-overlap: true` the aaa's aren't being drawn. On my screen, that happens with `symbol-spacing` higher than 480. Perhaps you should report this to the issue tracker.